# Windows authentication sucess while accessing using IP, but issue while accessing by computername

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-authentication

My issue is the title itself.

I am using IIS 7 and hosted an MVC 4 website which uses Windows Authentication (Windows Domain) for authenticating users.

I can access the site from browser

> using localhost ( from the server itself with admin previleaged user)
>
> using IP

I need to access the site using the computer name
My url will be `http://machinename.fullyQualifiedDomainname/AppFolderName`

But while trying to access using the above url, I am getting a Login box and I entered a valid
user ID and Password, but it says that you are not authorized to access.

I tried using the IP, I am getting the Login Box , I tried using the same userID and password. Then i can browse the website.

**I don't think its not an issue with DNS , because while giving the ComputerName, it identifies the server and prompting me with a login box. But it fails to validate the user
after that.**

Whether my observation is correct ?
Do I need to add any thing for achieving this ?

Comment: just check these urls:  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2009/12/31/things-to-check-when-kerberos-authentication-fails-using-iis-ie.aspx  
http://serverfault.com/a/240245/143232

Answer (score 0):

1) Try ping machinename.fullyQualifiedDomainname  to make sure it returns the correct IP first.

if the IP is correct,  then

2) Check your IIS entry.  To make sure machinename.fullyQualifiedDomainname is the IIS Binding.

Comment: thanks for your reply. First one is ok. But how to do the second step?  can u share some idea or link

Comment: If you are using IIS 7 or 7.5.  Do this. Open IIS, go to the sites folder on your left.  Then you'll see iis entries on your right.  Select the iis entry you want, and you'll see there's an option call "Bindings" on the right side.  Click on that, and you should see an existing binding. Click on edit and add machinename.fullyQualifiedDomainname as the HOST NAME.  Select the correct IP that matches machinename.fullyQualifiedDomainname's ip.  That should do the trick.

Comment: This I did and checked. Ok let me try to do once again and update you. Thanks for your support